# Angular - Routing layout step

Tags: angular

We are creating a form layout with 7 different steps. For each step contains more business logical (for example, validate that's the name it's correct, display all countries, etc.)

But, currently we have a one component with all logical inside (7 steps). The HTML contains 6.000 lines and the TS contains 7.000.

I assumed that we need a redefine this layout, I know! But the question is... how?

I think that the best practice it's creating for each step a component, for example, step1.component.

But, the "layout menu" of right now it's controlled with *ngIf. It's best practice replace this logical with (for example) route service?

Currently:

[image]

Comment: Can you upload that image here? Whatever it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i assume that the user has to go through the process and my not "jump" to any process step. If he could switch steps, then it gets a bit more complicated (but only a bit).

You could solve that with a router or by hand, depending on your need for URLs.

If you do not need a URL for each step, i would build it like that:

A main component, that has two areas. On the left side it will show the "ShowProcess" Component. It provides the information which process step is currently active.
And depending on the current active process step it shows a component that handles a specific form on the right side.

Your main component does only need the information "current process step form was finished successfully", then it could switch to the next process step.

Each process step component has the task to validate the inputs. When everything is fine, the user can proceed. Then parent component gets the info (and perhaps also the data) and can now switch to the next process step.

By the way, i would try to move most of the validation into [CustomValidators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators).
Also perhaps you can split a step process into multiple child components.

In my eyes, components are cheap. It needs some thinking to get the interfaces between those components right, but as a result your code gets decoupled. Now the code of each component is small and only dependent on "interfaces" to other components.
That allows you to change a component with less fear of breaking other components (as long as you don´t touch the interface :-) ).

I try to let my components not grow to big. If a component gets "big" (in my eyes more than 200 lines as a rule of thumb) i am always take some time to think about spliting it. The more complex the component, the harder I think. :-)

warm regards.
Jan

EDIT:
I forgot to mention services to encapsulate business logic. You dont wan´t to pollute your UI logic with business logic. When your UI changes, you do not want to break your business logic by mistake. The same is true vice versa.

If the different process steps are depending on their "own" backend calls, and if it is okay (or needed) when these backend calls will fire each time the corresponding process step is opened, then i would call those backend services in the corresponding process step.
By the way, the backend call itself and the mapping of the response into your frontend data structure, i would do in a service. So your component does not have to handle all these small things and can concentrate on its main task.

In my eyes their is no "best practice" of where to call the backend. In some cases you need to update the data for each visit to that component. Sometimes you need the data only at the beginning, ...
I would try to seperate the logic as much as possible (into a own service). And if the data needs to be retrieved only once, then i would store that data also in a central place. This could be in the service that does the backend call, that could be in a kind of proxy controller service that "controles" the backend service (the component talks to the proxy service and the proxy then decides if the backend service needs to be executed). Or it could be stored with the help of  full blown state management (e.g. NgRx -> Redux).
It always depends on your needs. BUT if you seperate the functionalites nicely, than it is at least easier to switch from one solution to the other if you need to.